# Remove file extension by using find, xargs

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to remove file extension 'log' by practice:

```
find -name "*.log" | xargs -t -I {} mv {} {{}%.log}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably just use `rename`:

```
find -name '*.log' | xargs rename .log ''
```

Or a shell script:

```
find -name '*.log' | while read f; do mv $f ${f%.log}; done
```

Comment: There are multiple `rename`s, which take different arguments.

Comment: Could you update your question to show specifically what you're trying to accomplish?  This seems to accomplish exactly what you're trying to do in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can simply use

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.log; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.log}"
done
```

Otherwise, use `find` to execute a shell whose argument is the file to rename; this allows you to use parameter expansion to strip the extension.

```
find -name '*.log' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.log}"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use bash parameter expansion like you want to, you need to assign the value to a parameter:

```
for file in $(find -name '*.log') ; do mv ${file} ${file%.log} ; done
```